# How to participate in block auctions as a parathread?

Tags: parathread, auctions

According to substrate and polkadot guides i learned that parathreads must participate in per block auctions (right?). But I can't figure out how to do this exactly. How to participate in such auctions and set a bid? From where can I manage that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "pay-as-you-go" functionality is not yet implemented for parathreads.

It is on the [roadmap](https://polkadot.network/launch-roadmap).

Currently, becoming a parathread is a first step prior to becoming a parachain. First you register as a parathread, then, upon winning a slot auction, the parathread becomes a parachain. More info on this process can be found here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/auctions-and-crowdloans/

You can read more about the envisioned mechanics of parathreads here:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parathreads#how-do-parathreads-operate

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: Any dates are known yet?

Comment: @ДанилаАлексеев is that implementation done for parathread?

Comment: @Paryaverse As I know it is not implemented yet. A few days ago i were trying to know the current status but have not found any related information